# Is it possible for an extension to get information about the web page inspected by DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am attempting to build extension that communicates with the DevTools page. My extension needs to get information about the web page that is being inspected on the DevTools page.

Is that possible?

I'm a beginner with regards to interacting with DevTools. I just don't want to spend time trying to write something if it is completely impossible. Thus, I am looking to know if it is possible.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to write a DevTools extension that interacts with the web page that is being inspected by DevTools. In fact, there is the [`devtools.inspectedWindow`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow) API which is intended for this purpose. That API, along with [`devtools.network`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.network) and [`devtools.panels][3]`, are used to make extensions for DevTools. You can read more about DevTools extensions at Chrome's [Extending DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) page.